# How the forced capture rule works with crowned pieces( in international checkers or...)

Tags: checkers

If there is a possible capture two or more fields away from a king like `b--w-` or `b-----w-` are those count as a compulsory/necessary jumps or not?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the [checkers/draughts variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts) that you are playing:

- For American checkers / Britisch draughts (which are two names for the same game) and Italian checkers, **kings are short-ranged** and cannot jump over empty squares.
- For all other variants (International/Russian/Spanish/Czech/Frisian/Thai draughts and Pool checkers), **kings are long-ranged** and can jump over empty squares as you indicated.

**NOTE**: in fact, for all but one (Thai draughts) of the long-ranged king variants, kings can also land on a sequence of adjacent empty squares behind a captured piece. In your notation, this would be patterns of the form `B- - -w- - -`, where the black king can land on any of the three `-` squares behind the white man.